# SSRS - Use Join() inside a tablix outside a group

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2017 with Reporting Services and Report Builder 2016.

I got a DataSet which looks like:
[image: DataSet example]

I've already created a tablix which groups by Name and shows each Name one time and the count of the Name in the table. Something like this:

> 4 x Foo
>   2 x Bar

Now, I want to get a text containing all comma separated Names (each Name only one time) and a text containing all comma separated Name counts. It should look like this:

> Foo,Bar
>   4,2

How is this possibile using SSRS Report Builder?

I already tried:

- Use Join() inside tablix (not working)
- Use a List instead of a tablix (generally working but it repeats the items vertically and not horizontally)

Answer (score 0):

Using the built-in functions you can combine `LookupSet` with `Join` like so:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!GRADE.Value, "DataSet1"), ", ")
```

Hopefully this explains how to use the `Join` function and reassures you that it is indeed possible. It also doesn't matter if you use a Table, List, or Matrix or if you are in a group or not.

However, this does not remove duplicate values or provide any sorting options. In order to do that, you have to add a custom function in the report properties. Once you do, the expression would look like this:

```
=Join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(LookupSet(Fields!ID.Value, Fields!ID.Value, Fields!GRADE.Value, "DataSet1")), ", ")
```

There are several examples of this VB code you can search for or implement yourself if you need this functionality.

Comment: Thank you. But using `Join()` in that way accesses the whole DataSet. I need the grouped DataSet since I want to get all Names and the count of each name as result. There is a third party application that got a text box for a comma seperated list of names and a second text box for a comma seperated list of the count. It matches the first name to the first value of the second text box, the second name to the second value and so on. I want the report containing thoose two strings so somebody can copy them and paste them to the text boxes.

Comment: You can concatenate the group ID to the field ID to limit to the current group. Like so: `=Join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(LookupSet(Fields!ID.Value & Fields!Name.Value, Fields!ID.Value & Fields!Name.Value, Fields!GRADE.Value, "DataSet1")), ", ")`

Comment: But then I only get a list containing each found Name. But I need a list containing a comma seperated list of names and a list containing a comma seperated list of the count of each name. This isn't possible with your solution, or am I wrong?

Comment: Oh, I see. Yeah, you could write custom code for that. Or better yet, use a separate dataset that does the aggregation in the database then lookup the result in the report. You can't dynamically aggregate those counts just using expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The code you would want is:

```
Public Shared Function RemoveDuplicates(ByVal items As Object()) As Object()

    System.Array.Sort(items)  
    Dim k As Integer = 0 

    For i As Integer = 0 To items.Length - 1  
        If i > 0 AndAlso items(i).Equals(items(i - 1)) Then  
            Continue For  
        End If  

        items(k) = items(i)
        k = k + 1  
    Next  

    Dim unique As[String]() = New[String](k - 1) {}  
    System.Array.Copy(items, 0, unique, 0, k)  
    Return unique  
End Function
```

You can use this via an expression using a `lookupset()` either within a region associated to a dataset or outside.

For outside, you can use:

```
=join(Code.RemoveDuplicates(lookupset(1,1, Fields!Name.Value, "DataSet1")), ", ")
```

Comment: Thanks. Please take a look at the comment I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54574207/ssrs-use-join-inside-a-tablix-outside-a-group/54577212#comment95972690_54576901).